Sens de l'adjectif « bell-lancastrien »
Cet adjectif se trouve dans   APHORISMES SUR LA SAGESSE DANS LA VIE, d'Arthur Schopenhauer (première traduction par J. A. Cantacuzène).

Plus l'homme est jeune, plus il a encore à apprendre dans toutes les directions or la nature ne lui a réservé que l'enseignement mutuel que chacun reçoit dans le commerce de ses semblables et qui fait qu'on pourrait appeler la société humaine une grande maison d'éducation bell-lancastrienne, vu que les livres et les écoles sont des institutions artificielles, bien éloignées du plan de la nature.

Les dictionnaires ne sont d'aucun secours.

Il est évident qu'on a affaire à des noms propres. Il suffit de taper Bell et Lancaster dans un moteur de recherches. https://data.bnf.fr/16623580/methode_de_bell_et_lancaster/

Le traducteur a calqué l'allemand Bell-Lancastersche Erziehungsanstalt par
« éducation bell-lancastrienne ».
Nous sommes en présence d'un adjectif composé dont le second mot est un adjectif qui se termine par ienne.
Le suffixe -ien/ -ienne indique qu'il s'agit d'un adjectif formé à partir d'un nom, nom commun ou un nom propre. Le suffixe -ien est en particulier le suffixe le plus utilisé pour former des adjectifs à partir de noms de lieux, villes ou pays. Dans le cas présent on pourrait penser tout de suite à Lancastrien, habitant de Lancaster, mais ça n'aurait pas de sens ici. Lancaster est par ailleurs un nom propre très courant dans les pays anglo-saxons. Il suffit de trouver le bon Lancaster.
Si tous les adjectifs en -ien formés à partir de noms de pays ou de villes se trouvent en général dans la plupart des dictionnaires, il n'en va pas de même avec ceux formés à partir de noms de personnes. On pourra éventuellement trouver un tel adjectif dans un dictionnaire si le personnage est quelqu'un de très célèbre. Le TLFi répertorie shakespearien, hugolien ou euclidien, et quelques autres, mais pas thatchérien ou zolien, lesquels se trouvent dans le wiktionnaire, dictionnaire non conventionnel et collaboratif.  Et le wiktionnaire a effectivement aussi une entrée à lancastrien. Il mentionne tout autant ce qui est relatif à la Maison de Lancastre (cf. la guerre des deux roses) que ce qui est relatif à :

(Éducation) Relatif au système éducatif mutuel créé par Joseph Lancaster.

La référence à l'éducation mutuelle nous montre que nous sommes au bon endroit. Et de là si on est intéressé on peut trouver plus de renseignements à l'entrée Joseph Lancaster ou enseignement mutuel de Wikipedia.

La question porte sur le sens ; le tag  « sens » se trouve parmi les tags de  la question.

@LPH Le sens de bell-lancastrien est bien "relatif au système d'éducation initié par Lancaster et Bell". Tag sens:signification d'un mot ou d'une expression. Tag vocabulaire:
Recherche d'un mot ou demande de précisions sur son emploi.  Si ce que tu veux est une description du système, tu t'adresse ailleurs, et ça se trouve facilement sur internet, comme déjà dit.

Dans le texte de Schopenhauer, il est certain que l'adjectif ne réfère pas exactement au système de Bell et Lancaster. Vous n'abordez pas cette partie du sens.

La société humaine n'est pas une grande maison d'éducation selon leur système ; il y a donc un sens supplémentaire à mentionner.

Quand même ! Il est évident que ça veut dire « à la façon de » et la question demande explicitement le sens de l'adjectif. En  plus en disant que les dictionnaires ne sont d'aucun secours...

Ah, alors ce que tu voulais ce n'est pas le sens du mot mais une explication de texte. Deux choses différentes.  Tu aurais dû définir dans ta question ce qu'était que l'enseignement mutuel, le relier à Bell & Lancaster et demander une explication de la phrase, et pas du mot. De toutes façons hors-sujet ici. J'ai fait une réponse qui porte sur la langue, et pas sur les méthodes éducatives ou la philosophie.

Le système  c'est huit classes et des moniteurs ; il est évident aussi que ce n'est pas la façon de la société humaine.  En plus vous ne donnez pas le sens de « bell-lancastrien » mais de « lancastrien » .

Lire la première phrase, c'est une traduction littérale de l'allemand. Bon pour une fois bien traduit, car la traduction de Cantacuzène est réputée pour être bourrée d'erreurs.

D'accord avec tout ça, mais lorsqu'on parle du système bell-lancastrian d'éducation, « bell-lancastrien ne signifie pas ce qu'il signifie dans  « ppeler la société humaine une grande maison d'éducation bell-lancastrienne » ; il n'est plus question de moniteurs ou de classes.

"huit classes et des moniteurs " réduction bien simpliste. Le système c'est l'apprentissage par ses pairs, "réciprocité de l'enseignement entre les écoliers". Et il y a une figure de style qu'on appelle "image" et ça existe dans toutes les langues.

Personne n'a fourni une définition venant d'un dictionnaire ; « bell-lancastrian » est un adjectif dans un livre et il n'y a pas de définition de dictionnaire ;est-ce que c'est un hapax ?

@LPH C'est la traduction de Bell-Lancastersche et on peut former autant d'adjectif qu'on veut à partir d'u nom propre. J'habite à Pétaouchnok, je suis donc un pétaouchnokien. Je m'appelle Drosera et je suis un écrivain en herbe qui aura le Prix  Goncourt dans quelques années et dans 20 ans on parlera du style Drosérien comme on parle du style durassien ou mauriacien ....

Vous pouvez former tous les adjectifs que vous voulez, certes,, mais certain s sont dans les dictionnaires et d'autres pas ; ensuite, ce n'est pas parce que vous avez formé un adjectif que vous auriez attribué à cet adjectif un sens donné. Ma question est très claire : sens de « bell-lancastrien » ? La meilleure réponse semble être la mienne : ce serait un synonyme de « éducation mutuelle » (possiblement un hapax, comme ce n'est pas un mot dans les dictionnaires, mais ça reste à déterminer).

La meilleure réponse semble être la mienne, oui, tellement que ce n'était pas la peine de poser la question.

@LPH bell-lancastrien est un adjectif composé et le suffixe se met sur le deuxième nom, comme en allemand. Non,  ce n'est pas synonyme de « éducation mutuelle », ça veut dire "à la façon de l'éducation mutuelle telle qu'elle est décrite par B&L" parce qu'il y a diverses  écoles (dans le sens de mouvement) qui interprète l’éducation mutuelle à leur façon.

Ça ne cadre pas ; l'éducation de la vie c'est une sorte d'éducation mutuelle, et elle n'est pas à la façon de Bell et Lancaster.

@Frank Mais bien sûr, tellement que pour le prochain lecteur qui, lui, n'a pas la même chance d'avoir trouvé une solution, et qui cherche sur le FSE, il y a une réponse toute prête. Vous ne vous rendez pas compte, dans votre innocence, que si ce n'était que pour vous et vos beaux yeux l'organisation du SE ne conserverait pas toutes ces questions et réponses ; si elles sont conservées c'est parce qu'elles enrichissent le SE, et c'est pour cela que, vous, user Franck, avez la possibilité d'écrire vos questions et d'y répondre vous-même (béaba).

@LPH Questions fermées, downvotes... de plusieurs personnes... je suppose que tu penses qu'on a tous tort, et qu'on n'est là que pour te persécuter.

@Frank Je cherche toujours ces dictionnaires… je suppose que je ne vois pas très bien !

CAIRN.info fourni la possibilité de définir cet adjectif.

L’une des premières sources dont nous disposons - le rapport d’Alexandre de Laborde publié en octobre 1815 dans le premier numéro du Journal d’Éducation - nous permet de saisir les principes et règles de fonctionnement de cette nouvelle méthode : on y apprend en effet que l’enseignement mutuel, développé outre-Manche par Bell et Lancaster, repose sur le principe du monitorat (d’où l’appellation anglaise de « monitoring system ») par lequel le maître délègue à des moniteurs le soin de suivre des groupes d’élèves sur certains éléments d’instruction. Une classe d’enseignement mutuel peut ainsi regrouper plusieurs centaines d’élèves répartis en huit « niveaux » ou « classes » dans lesquels les élèves évoluent en fonction de leurs acquisitions, le tout orchestré par un maître qui transmet les consignes aux élèves moniteurs au moyen de signaux visuels ou sonores. Cette méthode se distingue aussi par l’instauration d’un apprentissage simultané de la lecture et de l’écriture, l’utilisation du sable et d’ardoises pour l’écriture, et les mouvements réguliers des élèves qui se déplacent fréquemment pour former de nouveaux groupes de niveaux travaillant sur un apprentissage précis sous l’autorité d’un moniteur.

Il s'agit donc d'abord d'un adjectif qui décrit un système d'éducation développé en Angleterre ; cependant on ne trouve pas de cas d'utilisation.

Relatif au système d'éducation développé en Angleterre par Bell et Lancaster, ou enseignement mutuel, dans lequel les élèves apprennent les uns des autres ; (système à opposer à celui de l'enseignement simultané).

Tel qu'employé dans le texte de Schopenhauer, il devient évident que cet adjectif prend un sens plus général.

par extension Relatif à l'enseignement mutuel en général.


C'est un classique que l'on apprend en l'histoire de l'éducation. En dehors de l'article de wikipedia sur le sujet les références sont très nombreuses. 1, 2 etc.

@None Vos références vous donnent la possibilité d'écrire une réponse ; je ne peux pas les ajouter à la mienne ; c'est votre travail, pas le mien.

La description des méthodes d'enseignement n'est pas une question de français.

La question elle-même peut-être résolue en cherchant dans un dictionnaire, ce qui est un motif de clôture sur FSE.

@Frank Quel dictionnaire avez-vous donc ? Aucun.

Aucun dictionnaire n'a été trouvé.
